# How to properly configure the gorutine limit?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I have a task where three functions are performed if they are selected to work. I want to limit the number of horoutines per function. For example so that each of them has only a maximum of 10 goroutines running.

```
func main() {
    checkMethod1 := true
    checkMethod2 := false
    checkMethod3 := true

    list := []string{"info1", "info2", "info3", "info5"}

    for _, value := range list {
        value := value
        if checkMethod1 {
            go func() {
                //use value
                fmt.Println(value)
            }()
        }
        if checkMethod2 {
            go func() {
                //use value
                fmt.Println(value)
            }()
        }
        if checkMethod3 {
            go func() {
                //use value
                fmt.Println(value)
            }()
        }
    }
    //finish
    fmt.Println("All done")
}
```

I know that you can limit the number of goroutines to a pool of workers. But if I make one pool of workers with a limit of 10 goroutines, that number is divided by 3 tasks, and I need each function to have 10 goroutines.

I could create 3 pools, but that doesn't seem like a workable way to me.

I would like to use this library to create working pools: https://github.com/sourcegraph/conc

Comment: You can simply create 10 goroutines in each function

Comment: @Burak Serdar You mean the for loop? I need to wait for all functions to do their work, and then print the completion. Excuse me if I don't understand something.)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you are asking. Do you have a long-running loop with three options (checkMethod 1, 2, 3), and want to limit the number of goroutines created for each to 10?

Comment: @Burak Serdar That's right.

Comment: If you want to block making new goroutines at some limit, use a semaphore. A buffered channel makes a fine semaphore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it: use a buffered channel for each option, so you can limit active goroutines:

```
m1:=make(chan struct{},10)
m2:=make(chan struct{},10)
m3:=make(chan struct{},10)
wg:=sync.WaitGroup{}

for _, value := range list {
   value := value
   if checkMethod1 {
       m1<-struct{}{}
       wg.Add(1)
       go func() {
           defer func() { 
              <-m1 
              wg.Done()
           }()
           // do work
       }()
   }
   if checkMethod2 {
       m2<-struct{}{}
       wg.Add(1)
       go func() {
           defer func() { 
               <-m2 
               wg.Done()
           }()
           // do work
       }()
   }
   ...

  wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: how do I wait until all the goroutines are finished, and only then print about the completion?

Comment: Add a waitgroup. See updated answer

Comment: It turned out to be so simple.

Comment: And if I need 100 functions, should I create 100 semaphore channels?

Comment: If you want to limit to 100 goroutines each, yes.