# 1 pool for 3 different tasks with the same number of workers on each task

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm a bit confused how I can make it so that I create 1 pool where I make submissions to 3 different tasks, but still have the same number of workers for each task.

I already created such a [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76081910/how-to-properly-configure-the-gorutine-limit) and there I was advised to use semaphores. But in my task because of the large number of tasks a lot of goroutines are created. So I would like to limit the number of goroutines.

Here's an example of what I'd like to accomplish (here I use the [pond](https://github.com/alitto/pond) library as an example):

```golang
pool := pond.New(40, 0, pond.MinWorkers(40)) // 40 workers on each task

pool.Submit(func() {
      //task 1 with 40 workers
})

pool.Submit(func() {
      //task 2 with 40 workers
})

pool.Submit(func() {
      //task 3 with 40 workers
})

pool.StopAndWait()
```

**I may be talking nonsense, but I'd like some direction.**

Comment: Hmm, maybe you could create a slice of semaphores and try to acquire it inside each task. You can continue to use the pond library or reach for errgroup and just let the semaphores do the limiting for you.

Comment: Why don't you just have three pools? Surely that does exactly what you want. I had a look at your previous question and you say you don't want to but don't say why.

Comment: @RichardHuxton because 3 pools are just an example, in my task I will have more than 3 pools and I would not like to create a separate pool for each task. I don’t want to because a lot of goroutines are starting to be created that constantly load the system